# Keras LSTM network predictions align with input

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

The above may sound ideal, but I'm trying to predict a step in front - i.e. with a look_back of 1. My code is as follows:

```
def create_scaled_datasets(data, scaler_transform, train_perc = 0.9):
    # Set training size
    train_size = int(len(data)*train_perc)
    # Reshape for scaler transform
    data = data.reshape((-1, 1))
    # Scale data to range (-1,1)
    data_scaled = scaler_transform.fit_transform(data)
    # Reshape again
    data_scaled = data_scaled.reshape((-1, 1))
    # Split into train and test data keeping time order
    train, test = data_scaled[0:train_size + 1, :], data_scaled[train_size:len(data), :]

    return train, test

# Instantiate scaler transform
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(1, 1), activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(1, 1), activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(2, input_shape=(1, 1), activation='tanh', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Create train/test data sets
train, test = create_scaled_datasets(data, scaler)

trainY = []
for i in range(len(train) - 1):
    trainY = np.append(trainY, train[i + 1])

train = np.reshape(train, (train.shape[0], 1, train.shape[1]))
plotting_test = test
test = np.reshape(test, (test.shape[0], 1, test.shape[1]))

model.fit(train[:-1], trainY, epochs=150, verbose=0)
testPredict = model.predict(test)

plt.plot(testPredict, 'g')
plt.plot(plotting_test, 'r')
plt.show()
```

with output plot of:

[image]

In essence, what I want to achieve is for the model to predict the next value, and I attempt to do this by training on the actual values as the features, and the labels being the actual values shifted along one (look_back of 1). Then I predict on the test data. As you can see from the plot, the model does a pretty good job, except it doesn't seem to be predicting the future, but instead seems to be predicting the present... I would expect the plot to look similar, except the green line (the predictions) to be shifted one point to the left. I have tried increasing the look_back value, but it seems to always do the same thing, which makes me think I'm training the model wrong, or attempting to predict incorrectly. If I am reading this wrong and the model is indeed doing what I want but I'm interpreting wrong (also very possible) how do I then predict further into the future?

Comment: It is definitely possible that your LSTM has learned what you haven't yet: that the best possible predictor for the future, given all past data, is just the last data item. For instance, in the stock market this is a very good assumption. Other data series may be predictable, but this is not a given.

Answer (score 0):

To add on @MSalters' comment, and somewhat basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65314347/913098), it is possible, although not guaranteed that you could "help" your model learn something better than the identity, if you force it to learn not *the actual value* of the next step, but instead, make it learn *the difference* from the current step to the next.
To take this one step further, you could also keep an exponential moving average and learn the difference from that, somewhat like was done [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04110.pdf).

In short, it makes statistical sense to predict the same value, as it is a low-risk guess. *Maybe* learning a difference won't converge to zero.

---

Other things I noticed:

1. Dropout - no need to use any normalization before you were able to over-fit. It just complicates debugging.
2. Just one step into the past - it is likely you are losing a lot of required information, thus in fact forcing your net to have no idea what to do, and thus guess the same value. If you even gave it a single value more into the past, it could have a nice approximation of the derivative. That sounds important (only you know)